# Updating list elements with elements from another list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following lists:

```
original = [{'id': '1', 'updated': '01-03-2020 15:00:00'}, {'id': '2', 'updated': '01-03-2020 12:00:00'}] 
updated = [{'id': '1', 'updated': '01-03-2020 17:00:00'}]
```

How can I update the original list with the updated list?

Expected output is:

```
[{'id': '1', 'updated': '01-03-2020 17:00:00'}, {'id': '2', 'updated': '01-03-2020 12:00:00'}]
```

I can only think of doing it in 2 for loops like so:

```
for o in original:
    for u in updated:
        if u['id'] == o['id']:
            o['updated'] = u['updated']
```

Comment: `{i['id']: i for i in updated}`… You now have a dict which you can access directly by id…

Comment: Share whatever you tried, show your efforts please ;)

Comment: why do you work with lists, not dicts?

Comment: it's a list of dicts...

Comment: exactly, why not dict of dicts... id looks like unique key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better performance and accessing facilities, I'd suggest to use `dict` :

```
original = [{'id': '1', 'updated': '01-03-2020 15:00:00'},
            {'id': '2', 'updated': '01-03-2020 12:00:00'}]
original = {values['id']: values['updated'] for values in original}
print(original)  # {'1': '01-03-2020 15:00:00', '2': '01-03-2020 12:00:00'}

updated = [{'id': '1', 'updated': '01-03-2020 17:00:00'}]
updated = {values['id']: values['updated'] for values in updated}
print(updated)  # {'1': '01-03-2020 17:00:00'}
```

Then just, look for the key in `updated` and take in from the `original` if you don't find it

```
result = {id: updated.get(id, value) for id, value in original.items()}
print(result)  # {'1': '01-03-2020 17:00:00', '2': '01-03-2020 12:00:00'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: Original is a variable that represent a list containing dictionary object. So you can simply update original using list and dictionary indexing methods

```
original = [{'id': '1', 'updated': '01-03-2020 15:00:00'}, {'id': '2', 'updated': '01-03-2020 12:00:00'}]
updated = [{'id': '1', 'updated': '01-03-2020 17:00:00'}]

original[0]['updated'] = '01-03-2020 17:00:00'
print("updated original item:", original[0]) # This shows the updated index in the list
print("original:", original) # this shows the full list with its updated item.
```